# JavaScript - Blackjack Multiple Deck Creation + Shuffling

Tags: javascript

I've set up a variable `num_decks` (which is the number of decks that the user wants) that I pass into the function `createDecks()`. The trouble is, I have no idea how I can have the function create objects on its own, since I don't have a class set up. I've only got two working functions, which are `getDeck()`, and `shuffle(deck)` respectively, that create an ordered deck and proceed to shuffle it 1000 times.

---

TL;DR Bottom line, can I continue making it with functions? If not, then is there a way to salvage the code so then it can create multiple deck instances and then shuffle them? If so, then how?

I don't have much experience w/ OOP, mostly procedural, hence a lot of functions.

Code:

```
//arbitrary number, user can pick whichever one they want. Six is standard though. Technically inside a different function, but I placed it here just because.
const num_decks = 6;

function getDeck() {
    var deck = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
        for (var i = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
            var card = {Value: values[x], Suit: suits[i]};
            deck.push(card);
        }
    }
    return deck;
}

function shuffle(deck) {
    //can change this, but currently 1000 shuffles
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
        var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
        var tmp = deck[location1];

        deck[location1] = deck[location2];
        deck[location2] = tmp;
    }
}

//I have no idea how to accomplish it
function mergeDecks(num_decks) {
    for (var i = 0; i < num_decks; i++) {
        //somehow create new decks
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely do this without using classes. If you want to code these yourself, feel free, but a number of playing card libraries and blackjack libraries exist, which could save you a lot of work

Comment: I've been trying to find the library, could you provide me the name?

Comment: I'm sure there are many out there, here are 3 that were in my bookmarks: [mitch-b/typedeck](https://github.com/mitch-b/typedeck), [theaccordance/card-dealer](https://github.com/theaccordance/card-dealer), [Emobe/croupier](https://github.com/Emobe/croupier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class is nothing more than a blueprint for an object. You can create a class and then build objects using it, or just create objects individually, as you have already done using object literals. I created a quick function using an object literal to create the cards for x number of decks. Since you are only creating it in one place, a class isn't necessary.

```js
let num_decks = 6;

function createDecks(num_decks){
  let suits = ['Diamonds','Hearts','Spades','Clubs'], ranks = ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King'], deckArr = [];
  for(let i=0;i<num_decks;i++){
    let curDeck = [];
    for(let j=0;j<suits.length;j++){
      for(let k=0;k<ranks.length;k++){
        curDeck.push({'rank': ranks[k], 'suit': suits[j]})
      }
    }
    deckArr.push(curDeck);
  }
  return deckArr;
}

let deckArr = createDecks(6);
deckArr.forEach((deck,idx) => {
  let ranCard = deck[Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)]
  console.log(`random card from deck ${idx+1}`,ranCard)
});
```

If you wanted to create a class for code clarity, or to create cards uniformly in more than one place, it really doesn't involve changing your existing code much. Here is the same code using a class instead of an object literal:

```js
let num_decks = 6;

class Card{
  constructor(suit, rank){
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
  }
}

class Deck{
  constructor(){
    let suits = ['Diamonds','Hearts','Spades','Clubs'];
    let ranks = ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King'];
    this.cards = [];
    for(let j=0;j<suits.length;j++){
      for(let k=0;k<ranks.length;k++){
        this.cards.push(new Card(suits[j], ranks[k]));
      }
    }
  }
}

function createDecks(num_decks){
  let deckArr = [];
  for(let i=0;i<num_decks;i++){
    deckArr.push(new Deck());
  }
  return deckArr;
}

let deckArr = createDecks(6);
deckArr.forEach((deck,idx) => {
  let ranCard = deck.cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 52)];
  console.log(`random card from deck ${idx+1}`,ranCard)
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I was stuck on this because my brain kept on thinking the only way to solve this was to create a class, so I didn't even bother thinking of other options because I was so fixated lol.

Answer (score 1):

let me know if this works for you or if you don't understand some of the minor changes I made to your code.

```js
const num_decks = 6;
const suits =['spades','hearts','club','diamonds']
const values=['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','jack','queen','king','ace']

var decks = [];

for(let i = 0;i < num_decks; i++){

decks.push(getDeck())
decks[i] = shuffle(decks[i])

}

var oneBigDeck = mergeDecks(num_decks)
console.log(oneBigDeck.length)



function checkDeck(card) {
  return card['Value'] == 'ace';
}

var test = oneBigDeck.filter(checkDeck);
console.log(test.length) //4 aces * 6 decks = 24




function getDeck() {
    var deck = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            var card = {Value: values[j], Suit: suits[i]};
            deck.push(card);
        }
    }
    return deck;
}

function shuffle(deck) {

    //can change this, but currently 1000 shuffles
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var location1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
        var location2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * deck.length));
       
        var tmp = deck[location1];

        deck[location1] = deck[location2];
        deck[location2] = tmp;
    }
    return deck
}

//I have no idea how to accomplish it
function mergeDecks(num_decks) {
    var  masterDeck = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num_decks; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < 52; j++){
        masterDeck.push(decks[i][j])
        //somehow create new decks
      }
    }
    return masterDeck
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works. I see in the `mergeDecks` option you have two `for` loops, one iterating over `num_decks`, and the other one over 52 cards, or just a whole deck itself. I'm just curious how it still is able to maintain/keep the `value` and `suit` for each card even though it's not directly mentioned inside of the function.
Did I misread the code or something?

Comment: accept the answer and I'll tell you how it's done!

Comment: you can always change it

Comment: yeah but I feel like the other one is more comprehensive